# Filter out elements and replace element value in one step

Tags: xslt

I am trying to filter out elements, and rename element value, but I can't get it to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="product[matches(code, 'C17.*[^V]$')]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'Apple','Carrot')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example input data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <product>
      <code>C17020</code>
      <title>Apple</title>
   </product>
     <product>
      <code>C1723V</code>
      <title>Samsung</title>
   </product>
</xml>
```

I want to leave `<product>`'s starting with C17, but not ending to V. I use `C17.*[^V]$` regex for this. This part is working.

The problem is with renaming title function. If I add this step to a new XSLT with code:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

at the begin, then it works.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It may be a typo in your question, but your XSLT is selecting `produkt`, but it is `product` in your XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are doing `<xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>` in your template matching `xml`. This will copy the attributes and child nodes, buy will not apply any templates. So your template matching `title` is just not used.

You need to use `xsl:apply-templates` here, but also include the identity template (the template you mention using in your new XSLT code) which ensures `code` gets copied too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="product[matches(code, 'C17.*[^V]$')]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'Apple','Carrot')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note you can actually simplify your XSLT. Rather than being explicit in what you want to copy, by using the identity template you can instead have templates to remove what you don't want to copy....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product[not(matches(code, 'C17.*[^V]$'))]" />

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'Apple','Carrot')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another thing to note is that `matches` and `replace` is for XSLT 2.0 only.